# Database check condition with day,month,year columns

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have table that contains first three columns day, month, year. I have kept it separated instead of making single column date, because this table contains information about subscription analysis. So by keeping separated I can analyze data on daywise. Now I have situation where I want to reset few data. Example like I want to reset data which day, month, year comes between date 2008-01-01 and 2010-10-01. So how can I make where condition in mysql query for separated day, month and year columns?

Comment: Please add to your question a tag for the form of `SQL` that you are using, such as `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.

Comment: Store dates/dates and times as a single entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really store the value as a date.  But you can still do what you want.  Here is one way:

```
where year * 10000 + month * 100 + day between 20080101 and 20101001
```

Note that values are all integers.  A date would be better because the query could take advantage of an index.

Comment: Gordon Linoff thanks. your answers works nice. thanks alot. and also i know that date will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( yearValue,
                           '-',
                           monthValue,
                           '-',
                           dayValue ) ) BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND 
                           '2010-10-01'
```

This clause uses the `CONCAT()` function to form a string representation of the date being examined, then the `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert that string to a `DATE` value which is then compared to the range specified.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Further Reading**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between (on MySQL's `BETWEEN` operator)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat (on MySQL's `CONCAT()` function)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date (on MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE()` function)

Answer (score 0):

You may concatenate your three `INT` columns with the `TO_CHAR` function. The transform that into a date using `TO_DATE`, and then compare.

```
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(year || month || day), 'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN '20080101' AND '20100101';
```

Comment: alejandrohiron thank you. your answer is right but i am using mysql which does not have TO_DATE function

Comment: No worries! The question didn't have the RDBMS tag when I answered it.

Comment: You can also use the MySQL function `STR_TO_DATE()`. More information here: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/to_date